# Server-side rendering with Highcharts in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I want to add highchart on Doc report on a web API based Angularjs (ASP.NET MVC 5) application. Everything related to the chart needs to be done on C#. I have used http://export.highcharts.com/ .I have tried possible solution from this [C# Server Side rendering](https://sochix.ru/using-highchart-js-on-a-server-side/) suggested tutorial but the final image is invalid. My code is below.

```
string outputFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("image.jpg");
var settings = new HighchartsSetting
{
  ExportImageType = "jpg",
  ImageWidth = 800,
  ServerAddress = "http://export.highcharts.com/"
};

var client = new HighchartsClient(settings);
var options = new
{
  xAxis = new
  {
    categories = new[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar" }
  },
  series = new[]
  {
    new { data = new[] {29.9, 71.5, 106.4} }
  }
};

var res = await client.GetChartImageFromOptionsAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(options));
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(outputFile, res);
```

Is there any others way or any solution?

Comment: If the response is already an image, just write it to the target file.

Comment: The response returns byte and after writing it on file the image shows invalid.

Comment: Invalid how? What format did you request? Your `options` object shows categories and data but not the desired format, ie svg, png, jpg

Comment: I request jpg, png but both are invalid. I have also tried with settings var settings = new HighchartsSetting
    {
        ExportImageType = "jpg",         
        ImageWidth = 1500,
  ServerAddress = "http://export.highcharts.com/"
 };

    var client = new HighchartsClient(settings)

Comment: Edit the question, add all relevalnt code and a link to the library you use. Don't force people to guess. Perhaps you use [highcharts-export-client](https://github.com/sochix/highcharts-export-client), perhaps not. Nobody is going to follow a link to a tutorial with an invalid server certificate

Comment: I have edit the question. Please help.

Comment: If you check the response you'll see it's a URL to the image, not the image itself.

Comment: The response returning an array of byte not URL.

Comment: And what does that byte array contain? How big is it? You still haven't explained which library you use, but if it's `highcharts-export-client`, the result is a URL no matter which method you use. That library is an extremely thin wrapper on top of the Highcharts API that isn't really worth the trouble

Comment: Sorry. The response is: res = {byte[49]} .  Value is like [0] = 99, [1] = 104. etc. Th elibrary is highcharts-export-client from that tutorial.

Comment: If you check the page at http://export.highcharts.com/ you'll see it submits a JSON object with all settings. The library you probably used POSTs form data instead. It could be that HighCharts only returns images when the JSON payload is used. After all, `highcharts-export-client` was abandoned 3 years ago, the API may have changed A LOT in the meantime

Comment: Don't use that library then. It's 3 years old. The API has changed

Comment: Is there any suggestion which could help me?

Comment: Use the URL to download the image. Or use the GetChartImageLinkFromOptionsAsync to get the URL as a string. The request is the same, the only thing that changes is the value of the `async` parameter. Better yet, check HighChart's API and use it directly, it's not complicated. If you [read the code of HighchartsClient](https://github.com/sochix/highcharts-export-client/blob/master/HighchartsExportClient/HighchartsClient.cs) you'll see it's *very* simple

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of how to receive the image from Url?

Comment: HttpClient.GetAsync ?? HttpClient is well documented.

Comment: @Md Mahmudul Hasan. So, what did you end up with? Any code to share?

Comment: @Mark I have modified several parts of the above solution & received image an png. I can provide you c# solution library if you need it.

Comment: I@Md Mahmudul Hasan. Yes, please I'd like to see it.

Comment: @Md Mahmudul Hasan. Do you mind sharing your code?

Comment: @Mark Sorry for the late reply. I have added my solution. [Highchart Library](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14tapUWIDCotxUJ1xtGmpWRp0H25pgI1i/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks! Will have a look.

Comment: Your solution is working, thanks. I was wondering if I could ask you a few questions.

Comment: @Mark, yes, please. sorry for the late reply.

Comment: I see that this line: string imagePath2 = GetFromInternalServer(highchartDat); is not creating an image. Is that right?

Comment: In GetFromInternalServer(highchartDat) method,I create an image & save it to local folder. server.ProcessHighChartsRequest(highChartsData) is the method that return a png image by running highchart server.

Comment: Is there any way I could contact you privately?

Comment: But the line that writes file down is commented out: //File.WriteAllBytes(outputFile, response);

Comment: Ok, I uncommented it and getting a png image, But it's not correct and has a smaller number of bytes than the one produced by ProcessHighChartImageFromExportServer.

Comment: The export server is safe to use as Azure does not provide permission to run Phantom.exe. Later we moved to the Export server one from running server internally. We had an option to return byte that  Internal server previously. Hope your purpose serve with this.